# Show time series is stationary

Tags: time-series, stationary-processes

I have the following time series $$y_t = (-1)^tx_t$$

whereby $x_t$ is an AR model, $$x_t=\frac{1}{2}x_{t-1}-\frac{1}{3}x_{t-2}+\epsilon_t$$

with $\epsilon_t \sim \text{W(0, 1)}$ , show that $y_t$ is stationary.

So, I know also by the following $x_t = y_t-y_{t-1}$, so we should have $x_{t-1}=y_{t-1}-y_{t-2}$,

Therefore, combining all of this,

$$y_t=(-1)^t\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(y_{t-1}-y_{t-2}\right) + \frac{1}{3}\left(y_{t-2}-y_{t-3}\right) \right] + \epsilon_t$$

How do I proceed from here, I have thought to put all terms with respect to $y$ on LHS, to group, and collect the difference operator to solve the roots to a cubic?

Comment: I am not sure from where you get that $x_t = y_t - y_{t-1}$ and I think it only complicates it for you. Take the characteristic function of the process $x_t$ and show it is stationary. If $x_t$ is stationary, then $y_t$ clearly is also (why?). Mind you, I am assuming you are asked to show it is weakly stationary. Does this help?